# Save multiple records in database with one single click Razor Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, post, razor-pages

I'm developing a survey app with razor pages in ASP.NET.

The main tables, Questions and responses are related one to many.

In code, the *model* of the **responses** table is:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Response { get; set; }
public int Idquestions { get; set; }
public int Idapplicants { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Idapplicants")]
public virtual Applicants IdapplicantsNavigation { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Idquestions")]
public virtual Questions IdquestionsNavigation { get; set; }
```

The *model* of the **Questions** table is:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Nameq { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SurveysQuestions> SurveysQuestions { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Responses> Responses { get; set; }
```

The survey *view* is as follows, (questions are displayed with a foreach loop):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <section class="rounded" style="
        background-color: #404040;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding:30px;
        width:50%;
        color:white;

">
        <form method="post">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
            {

                if (Model.idq.Contains(item.Id))
                {

                    @Html.DisplayFor(name => item.Nameq)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input asp-for="Responses.Response" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Responses.Response" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>

                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Responses.Idquestions" value="@Model.idq" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Responses.Idapplicants" value="@Model.ida" />

                }
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success float-right" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </section> 
</div>
```

UPDATE

Survey *controller*

```
public class SurveyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly tausV1.Data.tausV1Context _context;

        public SurveyModel(tausV1.Data.tausV1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [TempData]
        public int ida { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public List<int> idq { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public IList<int> ids { get; set; }

        public IList<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
        public IList<Surveys> Surveys { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Responses Responses { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(int tempida, int tempidv)
        {
            Surveys = await _context.Surveys.ToListAsync();
            ids = new List<int>();
            Questions = await _context.Questions.ToListAsync();
            idq = new List<int>();
            ida = tempida;

            foreach (Surveys s in Surveys)
            {
                _context.Entry(s).Collection(x => x.VacanciesSurveys).Load();
                foreach (VacanciesSurveys vs in s.VacanciesSurveys)
                {
                    if (tempidv == vs.Idvacancies)
                        ids.Add(vs.Idsurveys);
                }
            }

            foreach (Questions s in Questions)
            {

                _context.Entry(s).Collection(x => x.SurveysQuestions).Load();
                foreach (SurveysQuestions sq in s.SurveysQuestions)
                {
                    if (ids.Contains(sq.Idsurveys))
                        idq.Add(sq.Idquestions);
                }
            }  
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
                _context.Responses.Add(Responses);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

**How can i save all responses, (in the database responses table), with a single click on Save button?**

Comment: What is the ViewModel on the page? What does your controller look like?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add it. I already updated it